# ul li not responsive in small device

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Li seems to be not responsive when I see in small device ,the value is going out of the container since it is long.

Below is the link where the code is hosted , you can see in small device when convert a value to sha256 ,the layout is getting distorted.

http://meanvj.github.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none
}
li {
  display:list-item;
  width: 100%; /* sometimes firefox gives issue*/
  word-break: break-all; /* break word in next line, if no space*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <h2>Hash Values</h2>
          <div class="well well-lg" id="display">
            <ul>
              <li>
                da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I just copied your code from browser, try this, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the property for that textbox

```
 word-wrap: break-word;
```

it will automatically get the scroll. click on that   [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap)